# Discord.js V12 Sending data from a json file into a single message

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I'm making a discord.js v12 bot and a command which lists orders from a json file it sends the json data like this: [image]

is it possible to make to make them in a single embed message?

the command's code:

```js
const fsn = require("fs-nextra");
const Discord = require('discord.js');
module.exports = {
    name: 'list',
    description: 'List of all orders',
    aliases: ['allorders'],
    execute(message) {
        

        // List Orders
        fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
            for(let x in orderDB) {
                const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()

                .setTitle('Here\'s a list of the current orders and their status.')
                .setDescription(`\`${x}\`: ${orderDB[x].status}`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
             message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
            }
        });
        
        



        // Logs in console.
        console.log(`${message.author.username} used the list command.`);
    }
}
```

the orders.json has the orders data stored in it like this:

```js
{
    "WLL": {
        "orderID": "WLL",
        "userID": "734532125021307001",
        "guildID": "745409671430668389",
        "channelID": "746423099871985755",
        "order": "a",
        "status": "Unclaimed",
        "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
    },
    "cwL": {
        "orderID": "cwL",
        "userID": "734532125021307001",
        "guildID": "745409671430668389",
        "channelID": "746423099871985755",
        "order": "test",
        "status": "Unclaimed",
        "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
    },
    "bvW": {
        "orderID": "bvW",
        "userID": "734532125021307001",
        "guildID": "745621984192364574",
        "channelID": "788863641339428864",
        "order": "a",
        "status": "Unclaimed",
        "ticketChannelMessageID": "not set"
    },
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it is possible, you can do it by moving the send message part outside of the loop, but then inside the loop build up a string...

For example:

```js
fsn.readJSON("./orders.json").then((orderDB) => {
    let orderString = "";
    for(let x in orderDB) {
        orderString = orderString + "`" + x + "`: " + orderDB[x].status + "\n";
        // add newline character at the end to display each "order" on a separate line
    }
    const exampleEmbed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
        .setTitle('Here\'s a list of the current orders and their status.')
        .setDescription(orderString)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter(message.member.user.tag, message.author.avatarURL());
    message.channel.send(exampleEmbed);
});
```

Comment: thanks, it works but it returns "defined" next to the orders in the embed

Comment: Do you have a picture?

Comment: Where does it say defined?

Comment: Ah sorry i was posting wrong comments i mean't to post this https://imgur.com/a/8I7YZmi

Comment: the first embed is when the json file is empty the second one is one there is one order

Comment: [image since its too long for a comment](https://imgur.com/VeH35XV)

Comment: so this isn't possible to fix?

Comment: It is late, but for anyone with a similar problem, the issue is with the 13th line where it starts by using the value of the variable, which is undefined.

If line 11 was changed to `let orderString = ""` then it would have a value from the start and wouldn't be undefined.

Alternatively, change line 13 to start with `orderString += "'"...` instead.